# How to redirect to ASP.NET Ideneity login page?

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

Using ASP.NET Identity, if I want to construct an `<a>` element that links to the Login page I can use Razor Helpers and some magic strings:

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

(Not the question at hand, but I'd be happy if someone would tell me why this convoluted collection of magic strings is somehow better than hardcoding the "/Identity/Account/Login" relative URL.)

My question is: If I want to return a redirect from a Handler routine (i.e., the C# code behind a razor page), **is there some recommended magic that I should be using to get a relative URL to the Login page?**

In other words, is there something better than:

```
return Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login");
```

Comment: [`RedirectToPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#url-generation-for-pages) is for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Actually, `RedirectToPage` (rather than `Redirect`) doesn't work if the Identity page hasn't been scaffolded.  Returning `RedirectToPage("/identity/account/login")` results in a redirect to `https://localhost:44360/?page=%2Fidentity%2Faccount%2Flogin` (your port number may differ) which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login", new { area = "Identity" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing RazorPages. Depending on how your mapping occurs in your program.cs, either add in your Web.config

```
services.AddRazorPages;
```

or in your .Net6 Programs.cs use

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages;
```

or if you are using endpoints, replace

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

with

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```